# Does $\mu(A)\geq 0, \mu(B)\geq 0 \Rightarrow \mu(A \cup B)\geq 0$?

Tags: measure-theory

Consider the following:

Let $\mu$ be a signed measure. And $(X,\mathcal{A})$ is a measurable space.

If $A,B \in \mathcal{A}$, such that $\mu(A)\geq 0$ and $\mu(B)\geq 0$. Does then $\mu(A \cup B)\geq 0$?

My Approach:

If $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, I would get $\mu(A \cup B)=\mu (A) + \mu (B)$.
And if they are not disjoint, I could just define:

$C_1:=A$

$C_2:=B \setminus A$

Then $\mu(C_1 \cup C_2)= \mu(C_1)+\mu(C_2) \geq 0$, since $0\leq \mu(C_2) \leq \mu(C_1) $.

Comment: Why is $0\leq \mu(C_2)$?  Consider $X=\{-1,1\}$ and $Y=\{-2,1\}$ where the signed measure is the number of positive elements minus the number of negative elements present in the set.  For both of these $\mu(X)=\mu(Y)=1-1=0$ however $\mu(\{-2,-1,1\})=1-2=-1$

Comment: Also, why $\mu(C_2)\leq\mu(C_1)$?

Comment: The punchline here is that $\mu$ is a *signed measure*, and that signed measures do not need to satisfy the same properties that non-negative measures do.  Your "*since*" line comes out of nowhere and is invalid.  Let it be a reminder that understanding definitions and having quintessential examples to think of, like here with the signed measure being number of positive minus number of negative, is incredibly important.

Comment: This "I suggest deleting the comment" is so polite and so rude at the same time, its like a signed polite formula.

Comment: @nicomezi and you suggest that I turn a blind eye when something blatantly incorrect remains written that would confuse future readers?

Comment: I would rather believe in the person in front of me to take the right decision when obviously shown that he/she is wrong. I am also not sure that this sentence had something to do with the actual deletion of the comment. My comment was mostly a joke though.

Comment: @JMoravitz you're absolutely correct, only glanced at post and missed the word signed. Thanks for the notice.

Comment: Thanks to all of you, I know I missed something (which was the fact that it was about signed measures).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Converting comment to remove from question queue*:

Consider the quintessential example of a signed measure formed by taking a counting measure over the positive numbers as the positive part, and by taking a counting measure over the negative numbers as the negative part.

Let $X=\{-1,1\}$ and $Y=\{-2,1\}$.

We have then $\mu(X)=\mu(Y)=1-1=0\geq 0$ while on the other hand we have $\mu(X\cup Y)=\mu(\{-2,-1,1\})=1-2=-1<0$

Comment: Thank you very much!